# selected value in Django forms.ChoiceField

Tags: python, django

Here i have the form

```
vote = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=(('1', '1',), ('2', '2',), ('3', '3',)), initial='2')
```

Django1.3 create from it the code

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

This selected-tag does not work. Should be

```
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh. I found out that this does not work only in FF5, in Chrome works fine... So sad. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: selected="selected" is correct: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Occasionally, I've seen browsers not select the appropriate option, even with selected="selected" when doing an F5 or Command + R (on Mac). However, doing a full refresh of the page (Ctrl + F5) in FF on Windows, or reloading the url from the address bar, will correctly select the selected option. FireFox does sometimes behave this way: http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/12/16/option-selectedselected-not-working/